# Why Api response is slow when using Async await with mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

When i am using `async` and `await` in `nodejs` its response is coming slow PRODUCT SCHEMA

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{ 
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
  name: {type: String, require: true}, 
  category_fields: { type:Object }, 
  name_list_fields: [{ type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'list' }], 
  full_name: { type:String },
  actual_price: { type: Number, default: 0 }, 
  selling_price: { type: Number, default: 0 }, 
  product_image_url_1: { type: String, default: "" }, 
  sku: { type: String, default: "" }, 
  brand:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'brand' }, 
  linked_offers: [{ type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'offer' }], 
  hot_deal: { type:Boolean,default:false}, });
```

CODE

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){


    productschema.find({delete_status: { $ne:  1}})
    .sort({_id:-1})
    .populate('brand similar_product linked_offers','name actual_price product_image_url_1 actual_price selling_price full_name offer_image_url offer_type offer_amount_percentage description')
    .skip( parseInt(req.params.index) )
    .limit( parseInt(req.params.limit) )
    .then(async productsrows => {            
        if(productsrows.length == 0){
          resolve({
            "success":false,
            "message":"No Data"
            })
          }else{
            try{
            var arrayListOfProduct = [];
            for(var i =0;i<productsrows.length;i++){
              var item = productsrows[i].toObject()
              item.in_stock = await commonFunctionAdmin.fetchProductCountInStock(productsrows[i]._id)
              arrayListOfProduct.push(item)
            }
            resolve({
                      "success":true,
                      "message":"Products fetched success",
                      "count":await fetchTotalProductCount({delete_status: { $ne:  1}}),
                      "data":arrayListOfProduct
            }); 
          }catch(e){
            console.log(e)
            resolve({
            "success":false,
            "message":"something went wrong"
            })
          }
        }
    })
 }) //STOCK COUNT
```

FUNCTION

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    stockSchema.aggregate([ 
        {$unwind: "$product"},
        {$unwind: "$product.imei"},
        {$match: {"product.imei.sold_status":false,"product.product":ObjectId(product_id)}},
        {$group: { 
        _id: null, 
        count: { $sum: 1 }
        } 
        }]).then(async rowsTotalRevenue => {
        if(rowsTotalRevenue.length > 0){
        resolve(rowsTotalRevenue[0].count)
        }else{
        resolve(0)
        }
        }).catch(e=>{
        console.log(e)
        resolve(0)
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you use await keyword, you save something like 200ms from each request (my experience). 
To understand what is happening in your application, you can put a timer in every essential step of your function, measure the time difference from start to finish. This is very simple to do, just check what hours the code started to be run.

> Async/await makes asynchronous code look and behave a little more like synchronous code. This is where all its power lies.

I tried to understand the code posted above and saw that you have some iterations in the array, know that all of this might be a bottleneck for your answer.

```
async function myCoolFunction () {
 var initial = new Date().getTime();
 var finalTime;
 // create a new promise inside of the async function
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    setTimeout(() => resolve(true), 1000) // resolve
  });

  // wait for the promise to resolve
  let result = await promise;

  finalTime = newDate().getTime();
}
myCoolFunction();

}
```

Comment: in My Case Issue was the mongodb server was not secured so that api response was slow now it is working fine